# I keep getting this error <undefined method `category_id' for #<ActionController::Parameters>>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im currently trying to create a search form and everytime I try to send a request rails always report me the NoMethodError above. Below is my code.

```
controller
    @search_cat = params['search_cat']
    if @search_cat.present?
      category_id = @search_cat['category_id']
      @tasks = Task.where(user_id: current_user.id, category_id: category_id.to_i)
    end
```

```
view
<%= simple_form_for :search_cat, url: tasks_index_path, method: "GET", html: { class: 'form-inline' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :category_id, collection: current_user.categories,as: :select %>
  <%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

```
  def tasks_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:deadline_at,:title, :tags, :note, :is_done, :category_id, :user_id, {tag_ids: []})
  end
```

edit:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :category, optional: true

  has_many :tag_associations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :tag_associations


end
```

```
schema
create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "deadline_at"
    t.string "title"
    t.string "note"
    t.boolean "is_done"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_tasks_on_category_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_tasks_on_user_id"
```

I basiclly just trying send the input from the search form to query controller.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDKNy.png)

Comment: Does `task` `belong_to` a `category`?  Can you share your `task` model code?

Comment: throw a `byebug` (or whatever debugger you're using) call in there and see what your params object contains

Comment: @RockwellRice yes

Comment: Can you post an example of exactly what the params look like when they get sent to the controller method?

Comment: Can you print out your controller params? Looks like you should reference the `task_params` here.

Comment: i acctually tried the byebug like @mrben522 recommended me. And it shows me this: Parameters {"category_id"=>"83"} permitted: false. Now Im trying to add the parameters to parm_tasks but it still doesnt work. I try :search_cat, {search_cat: []} and i even try to change the Parameter from category_id (from the form) to something else to not overlapping the already existing Parameter category_id (from model) but nothing works.

Comment: Your params should look like this `{task: {"category_id"=>"83"}}`.  It needs to be nested inside a `task` object.  You know for what you are doing it may be eaiser to not submit a form and just redirect to that page with the param.  Do you really need a form submission?  All the controller is doing is returning results that you grab from the param.  What ahppens if you jsut add the param to the view, does it work fine?

Answer (score -2):

My guess would be that you don't have a category reference set in your task table. I would double check your schema to make sure you have all the columns within your task table match your params that you are permitting in your controller. Also make sure you have your relationships set within your models between your task model and category model.

Comment: In the error, I saw that the category_id was blank, and that the key in params pointing to the object that contains the category_id was 'search_cat', and not task. I would like to see the byebug looks like when looking at the params coming in to your task controller.